# Get int from boost::gregorian::date_duration

Tags: boost

I have date_duration variable and i want to convert it to int, I found the same topic here, about how to convert for output by `<<`, but i don't want it. I have to use integer value for arithmetic operations. How to convert it to string or integer? I can write it to file and then `fscanf` but it's idiot method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `days()` method to get the number of days (as a value, not an object).